# How to make editable cell in controls:DataGrid in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

> [Update: I have solved this problem by making each column of the grid
>   IsReadOnly = false]

I want to make my control:datagrid editable. That is - In UI I want to edit the values in a cell. I have tried [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid). It can't make my cell editable. What is in my code:

```
<controls:DataGrid x:Name="grid"
                                   Grid.Row="1"
                                   Margin="40, 40, 40, 40"
                                   Height="Auto"
                                   Width="Auto"
                                   AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                   BorderBrush="LightGray"
                                   BorderThickness="1"
                                   GridLinesVisibility="All"
                                   AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue"
                                   HeadersVisibility="Column"
                                   CanUserSortColumns="True"
                                   Sorting="DataGrid_Sorting"
                                   FrozenColumnCount="2"
                                   ColumnWidth="150"
                                   ItemsSource="{Binding collection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                   IsReadOnly="False">
                        </Style>
                    </controls:DataGrid.RowStyle> -->
                </controls:DataGrid>
```

And, In xaml.cs:

```
public static ObservableCollection<object> collection { get; set; }
public static DataTable dataTable, tempTable;

grid.Columns.Clear();

for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
    {
        Header = dataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName,
        Binding = new Binding { Path = new PropertyPath("[" + i.ToString() + "]") }
    });
}


collection = new ObservableCollection<object>();


foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    collection.Add(row.ItemArray);
}
grid.ItemsSource = collection;
```

My target is to make something [like this in the figure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/resources/images/controls/datagrid/datagrid.gif)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem by making each column of the grid IsReadOnly = false. For example: grid.Columns[1].IsReadOnly = false;